# How to show all installed apps in a grid view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gridview

How to show all installed apps in a grid view,
How can I display a list of app icons in a gridview

MainActivity:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private List<AppList> installedApps;
        private AppAdapter installedAppAdapter;
        ListView userInstalledApps;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            userInstalledApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.installed_app_list);
    
            installedApps = getInstalledApps();
            installedAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
            userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
            userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
    
                    String[] colors = {" Open App", " App Info"};
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Choose Action")
                            .setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position of the selected item
                                    if (which==0){
                                        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(installedApps.get(i).packages);
                                        if(intent != null){
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, installedApps.get(i).packages + " Error, Please Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (which==1){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + installedApps.get(i).packages));
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, installedApps.get(i).packages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
    
                }
            });
    
            //Total Number of Installed-Apps(i.e. List Size)
            String  abc = userInstalledApps.getCount()+"";
            TextView countApps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countApps);
            countApps.setText("Total Installed Apps: "+abc);
            Toast.makeText(this, abc+" Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
        }
    
        private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<AppList> apps = new ArrayList<AppList>();
            List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
            //List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
                PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
                if ((!isSystemPackage(p))) {
                    String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                    Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
                    String packages = p.applicationInfo.packageName;
                    apps.add(new AppList(appName, icon, packages));
                }
            }
            return apps;
        }
    
        private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
            return (pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
        }
    
        public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    
            public LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            public List<AppList> listStorage;
    
            public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
                layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                listStorage = customizedListView;
            }
    
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return listStorage.size();
            }
    
            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }
    
            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
    
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
                ViewHolder listViewHolder;
                if(convertView == null){
                    listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list, parent, false);
    
                    listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
                    listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
                    listViewHolder.packageInListView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
                    listViewHolder.GridView = (GridView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    
                    convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
                }else{
                    listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
                listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
                listViewHolder.packageInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getPackages());
     //           listViewHolder.GridView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
    
                return convertView;
            }
    
            class ViewHolder{
                public GridView GridView;
                TextView textInListView;
                ImageView imageInListView;
                TextView packageInListView;
    
            }
        }
    
        public class AppList {
            private String name;
            Drawable icon;
            private String packages;
            public AppList(String name, Drawable icon, String packages) {
                this.name = name;
                this.icon = icon;
                this.packages = packages;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public Drawable getIcon() {
                return icon;
            }
            public String getPackages() {
                return packages;
            }
    
        }
        }
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backround"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countApps"
        android:text="Count: "
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/installed_app_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

installed_app_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_package"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="App Package Name"
                android:textSize="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you give me some source code of a simple grid view?
i want all installed app in a grid view

Thankyou .............................................

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recycler view for this purpose and set it's layout as Grid layout manager

simply add the  recycler view dependancy

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
```

Just create a new activity and test this example code
https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html